# Printing in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function that returns Floats (or some other type). I am using my program as a module in ghci. How would I print out info at certain points in the program? For example, if I detect bad input to a function, how do I print out an error message?

Comment: Have you seen the Haskell tutorial? http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few cases here, depending on what you want to do.

The straight forward sprinkling of `printf`s as a method of debugging is not going to work very well in Haskell.

If you have a partial function, I would suggest using Either or Maybe as a solution.

For example:

```
lookup :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
lookup x []                     = Nothing
lookup x ((k,v):ys) | x == k    = Just v
                    | otherwise = lookup x ys
```

`lookup` takes a key, and a list of key-value pairs and return Just the value associated with that key, or Nothing if the key is not in the list.

```
doMath :: Char -> Int -> Int -> Either String Int
doMath '+' x y = Right (x + y)
doMath '*' x y = Right (x * y)
doMath '/' x 0 = Left "Division by zero"
doMath '/' x y = Right (x / y)
doMath '-' x y = Right (x - y)
doMath  c  x y = Left ("Bad operator:  " ++ show c)
```

Either is like maybe, in that if you can, you will return the *right* result.  Otherwise you take what's *left*.

If your function really has an impossible case, then you can use the function `error`, which throws a pretty much uncatchable error with a string.  It's not pretty, but it will help point you in the right direction when doing a post-mortem after the impossible does happen.

Comment: "`Either` is the `Right` result, or what's `Left`." Thank you for this great trick for remembering how to use `Either`!

Answer (score 3):

Because there are no side effects in pure code, you basically have three options:

You can print an error message and throw an exception, which usually terminates the program unless you catch it:

```
myDiv x 0 = error "Division by zero"
myDiv x y = x / y
```

You can print an error message and return some value:

```
import Debug.Trace

myDiv x y = trace ("Trying to divide " ++ show x ++ " by " ++ show y) (x / y)
```

You can return a value which describes the error in some way, e.g. Maybe or Either String:

```
myDivMaybe x 0 = Nothing
myDivMaybe x y = Just (x / y)

myDivEither x 0 = Left "Won't divide by zero"
myDivEither x y = Right (x / y)
```

You usually use `error` when the input is really invalid and you don't mind a runtime error in that case. `trace` is usually used for debugging purposes. If you want to avoid runtime errors on invalid input, you can use Maybe or Either.